# Facebook login doesn't work with hello.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, hello.js

I've created a sample react app using create-react-app npm module. And then I have added hello.js to the application to be able to write a quick app using this api. I've correctly configured my app id and such at facebook developer site (I've tested this with another sample app without using hello.js and it works fine).

When I click on the Login button, it get redirected to FB login page, I enter the correct credentials and it gets redirected to localhost, but without a success response. For some reason this doesn't work. And I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Here's the code if anyone has ideas on what I'm doing wrong:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as hello from 'hellojs';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      askForLogin: true
    };

    hello.init({
      facebook: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" //correct api is provided here
    });

    hello.api("me").then(function(r){
      console.log("Successful login: ", r);
      this.setState({askForLogin: false});
    }, function(e) {
      console.log("Not successful yet");
      this.setState({askForLogin: true});
    });
  }

  login() {
    const options = { display: "page" };
    const cb = () => { console.log("Login callback");}
    hello.login("facebook", options, cb);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        {
          this.state.askForLogin ?
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.login}>Login to Facebook</button>
          </div> : <div></div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by explicitly telling hello.js to use 'facebook' and it worked immediately. Posting the answer so that if anyone else faces the problem, it might help them:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as hello from 'hellojs';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      askForLogin: true
    };

    hello.init({
      facebook: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    });

    const facebook = hello.use("facebook"); //This is the new line

    facebook.api("me").then(function(r){
      console.log("Successful login: ", r);
      this.setState({askForLogin: false});
    }.bind(this), function(e) {
      console.log("Not successful yet");
      this.setState({askForLogin: true});
    }.bind(this));
  }

  login() {
    const options = { display: "page"};
    const cb = () => { console.log("Login callback");}
    hello.login("facebook", options, cb);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        {
          this.state.askForLogin ?
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.login}>Login to Facebook</button>
          </div> : <div></div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```